# I'm not able to see anything In the UI

Tags: interface

[image]

All the regions of my user-interface outside the 3D view have disappeared, and I don't know what is happening. I can't find a way to fix it. What should I do?

Comment: Make sure your graphics drivers are up to date.

Comment: That's probably a graphic issue. You should investigate your card diver and settings.

Comment: @RobinBetts - You _do_ see the missing timeline, outliner, properties, and header, right?

Comment: @ChristopherBennett Ahhh! I see! Fair enough.

Comment: @Python_EXPyt Apologies for my earlier misunderstanding. I think this is probably a hardware issue, and so off-topic, but my previous reasons for closing were unfair. I'll leave it to others to decide.

Comment: Lol. Maybe "See" isn't the right word for it...